# how to use array instead of using And in if

Tags: vba

Is there any option to use and criteria in array because I have 4-5 criteria.
So is any option there or have to do same like below?

```
For Each c In rng
If c.Value <> "A" And c.Value <> "B" And c.Value <> "C" Then
 dic(c.Value) = c.Value
End If
Next c
```

Thank you

Comment: Select Case c.value:Case "A","B","C":Case Else:dic(c.value) = c.value:End Select

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more context which makes it difficult to provide a good answer. All I can think of is:

- You can do it also with a `Switch` but you are still applying the same logic than in an `if`.
- You could apply a `filter` to your range so that doesn't have nor A, B, C and you would avoid the `If` inside the loop.
- If you want to make it "shorter" but less readable (for the reason which I don't suggest this) you could convert your c in ASCII and then knowing that A-C are contiguous you can just see if the value is not between those that correspond to A-C. If you had more cases (and are still contiguous letters) can be decent I guess.

Comment: Thanks, no an issue I can use this too, but I was thinking there can be use array too , and since hours I was searching on google but not found any solution.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, but might not be more cleaner/easier: if `array`'s elements are A, B & C, then you can use a similar code to this pseudo-code:

```
For Each c In rng
    For each element in array
        If c.value <> array(element) Then count = count + 1 'how many times it is true
        End If
    Next element
    If count = NumberOfElementsOf(array) Then do your stuff with c
Next c
```

But if you had a lot of criteria it might be better. Of course it can be optimized e.g. if you check the opposite criteria and if that's true exit the loop - you can discover different opportunities.